# text-overflow: ellipsis not working when italic text overflows only one side of the container

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have the following example with italic text. The last letter of the text, since it's italic, overflows the container. However, because its width is still not overflowing "on both sides" of the container, there is no ellipsis shown. This letter can be fully shown by removing `overflow: hidden;` from css, but I need that for the other ellipsis. Is there any clean/simple way of handling both of these cases with just css?

```css
.main-container {
  background: yellow;
  width: 350px;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: impact;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.some-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class='main-container'>
  <div class='some-text'>
    <span>Some text in here which is a bit too long</span>
  </div>
  <div class='some-text'>
    <span>Overflow on letter S, no ellipsiS</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could add a tiny bit of right-side padding to the spans, `padding-right: 0.2em` (yes, "magic number", but in a font-size relative unit it should work pretty okay even for different font sizes, I guess.)

Comment: Whether you are actually using a font that has an "italic" variant, might also come into play here. If it doesn't, then the browser will simply "simulate" it by slanting the letters, and that usually gives different results, than an actual, _proper_ italic font.